# MS Access 2007 - Warning box everytime the database is opened is different from 2003

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Everytime I open my mdb copy to work on something, I get this little warning label that some somethings have been blocked....click this button to un block? anyway I can default that off?

thanks
justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your database's folder to trusted locations. You get there by Clicking on on the office button at the top left, then click Access Options. In the left side you will see a vertical list and it will have a menu item nearing the bottom titled Trust Center, click that and then select Trusted Locations.

Now you just need to click Add new location to add your folder so you can stop receiving trust warnings.

Comment: This is, by the way, "security theater," given that the registry keys involved are editable by end users (i.e., don't trigger a UAC prompt or pre-Vista, require admin access). The A2003 "macro security" is also "security theater" rather than actual security. I turn macro security to LOW and put all my databases in trusted locations as a matter of course in order to avoid this stupidity.